# NodeJS CSurf: ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token

Tags: node.js, angular, csrf

Using Angular and Nodejs as backend. csurf middleware throws Forbidden error, even if see the same _csrf token in the request cookie. My URL is: https://192.168.0.100.xip.io:64726/

```
Error log:
method is GET url is /
{"G_ENABLED_IDPS":"google","G_AUTHUSER_H":"0","_csrf":"XcUDRcxDPpje0nlNGdF4bZpn"}
method is POST url is /api/login/verify
{"G_ENABLED_IDPS":"google","G_AUTHUSER_H":"0","_csrf":"XcUDRcxDPpje0nlNGdF4bZpn"}
ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
   at csrf (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/csurf/index.js:112:19)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
   at urlencodedParser (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:100:7)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at /Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
   at Function.process_params (/Users/admin/nodejs/google-signin-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Nodejs:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var csrf = require('csurf')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const helmet = require("helmet");
// var session = require('express-session')
const uuid    = require('uuid/v4');
const app = express()
const parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
const csrfProtection = csrf({cookie:true,secure:true,httpOnly:false})
app.use(cookieParser())


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { method, url } = req;

  console.log(" method is "+ method + " url is " + url)
   logger.info('cookie', req.cookies)
next() 

})
app.get('/', csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
  console.log('app // get called')
  // Pass the Csrf Token
  tokenVal =  req.csrfToken();
  res.json({csrfToken: tokenVal });
  res.sendFile('index.html');
  
});

app.post('/api/login/verify',parseForm, csrfProtection,(req, res) => {
  verify(req.body.idToken)
    .then((result) => {
      let id = result['sub']
      logger.info('id=', id)
      res.send({
           'payload': result
         })
         
             }).catch(logger.error)
});
```

Comment: Are you passing the csrf cookie as well?

Comment: In the '/' route, I send once, res.json({csrfToken: tokenVal });. and in /api/login/verify I mention csrfProtection as a handler. I believe I am not setting cookie.

Comment: use this and then try
csrf({secure:true,httpOnly:false})

Comment: sure, if I set cookie:false should I remove cookieParser middleware too?

Comment: Yeah since we are not working with cookie then we can remove cookieParser

Otherwise we have to pass cookies with the request because csurf also creates a cookie in the request and it validates the csrf using the cookie and the value created with csrfToken()

Comment: encountered Error: misconfigured csrf error. Added back the cookieparser